# Reading and parsing a file from dropbox in swift

Tags: ios, swift, csv, parsing, swift5

I am following a tutorial on how to read and parse a csv file from dropbox in swift. However, the tutorial is 4 years old and my code is not compiling in swift5. The code example is copied below and the link to the original video tutorial is here https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=O6AKHAXpji0

I am getting two errors.

Error 1:

on the let request = line of callFileFromWeb(){}

```
'NSURL' is not implicitly convertible to 'URL'; did you mean to use 'as' to explicitly convert?
```

Error 2:

and on let session = ... within the httpGet(){}

```
'NSURLSession' has been renamed to 'URLSession'
```

When I try to implement the proposed fix for error two then I get another error

```
Cannot call value of non-function type 'URLSession`
```

Any ideas what should I be adjusting for it to work in swift5?

```
 var items:[(days:String, city:String, inches: String)]?

 override func viewDidLoad() {
     super.viewDidLoad()
        // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.
       callFileFromWeb()
    }

 func callFileFromWeb(){
        let request = NSMutableURLRequest(URL: NSURL(string: "https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/2813968/raindata.txt")!)
      httpGet(request){
          (data, error) -> Void in
            if error != nil {
                print(error)
            } else {
                print(data)//PRINTING ALL DATA TO CONSOLE
                let delimiter = ":"
                
                self.items = []
                let lines:[String] = data.componentsSeparatedByCharactersInSet(NSCharacterSet.newlineCharacterSet()) as [String]
                
                
                for line in lines {
                    var values:[String] = []
                    if line != "" {
                        values = line.componentsSeparatedByString(delimiter)
                        // Put the values into the tuple and add it to the items array
                        print(values[2])//PRINTING LAST COLUMN
                        let item = (days: values[0], city: values[1], inches: values[2])
                        self.items?.append(item)
                    }}//all good above
                //  self.AddDataToDatabase()
            }//there was an error
            
        }//end of request
        
    }//end of get data from web and load in database
    
    
    func httpGet(request: NSURLRequest!, callback: (String, String?) -> Void) {
        let session = NSURLSession.sharedSession()
        let task = session.dataTaskWithRequest(request){
            (data, response, error) -> Void in
            if error != nil {
                callback("", error!.localizedDescription)
            } else {
                let result = NSString(data: data!, encoding:
                    NSASCIIStringEncoding)!
                callback(result as String, nil)
            }
        }
        task.resume()
    }
```

The final goal is to be able to read a file from drop box. The file updates weakly, so when users launch the app they always have access to the most updated version of the file, rather than having to re download the app when the file updates. Is this the correct approach to do this?

Comment: This code is very old and uses some old classes but the logic for downloading hasn't changed much so I would advice you to find a much newer tutorial on downloading data using URLSession, URL, URLReqest etc and use it as a template and then apply the code handling the response to it.

Comment: Using [this simple example](https://www.hackingwithswift.com/example-code/networking/how-to-download-files-with-urlsession-and-downloadtask) should help you a lot

Comment: thank you. I will have a look and try to adjust based on this example. If I am able to solve the problem I will post the solution.

Answer (score -1):

A framework that proved useful in past projects with parsing `CSV` files is:

*CSwiftV* -> https://github.com/Daniel1of1/CSwiftV

**Updated: 9/23/2020**

Let me demonstrate it by refactoring your `callFileFromWeb()`:

```
    func callFileFromWeb() {
     let dropboxURL = URL(string: "https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/2813968/raindata.txt")
     URLSession.shared.dataTask(with: dropboxURL!) { data, response, error in 
        guard let urlData = data, error == nil else {
            return
        }
        let unparsedCSV = String(data: urlData, encoding: String.Encoding.utf8) ?? "Year,Make,Model,Description,Price\r\n1997,Ford,E350,descrition,3000.00\r\n1999,Chevy,Venture,another description,4900.00\r\n"
        let csv = CSwiftV(with: unparsedCSV)
        let rows = csv.rows
        var iteration = 0
        for row in rows {
            // Assuming you want the last row
            if iteration == rows.count - 1 {
                let item = (days: row[0], city: row[1], inches: row[2])
                self.items?.append(item)
            }
            iteration += 1
        }
    }
}
```

One other thing, remember that you need to download `CSSwiftV` from Github and copy the original `CSwiftV.swift` file into your project.

Hope this helps!

Comment: Would you be able to share an answer with code based on my example?